# Gridgain and Offheap settings

Tags: gridgain

I have 128GB server. I want to store as much as I can into the 128GB. So I figured I would use 120GB for Offheap and leave the rest for the OS.

In my cache.xml I put...

```
<property name="memoryMode" value="OFFHEAP_TIERED"/>
<property name="offHeapMaxMemory" value="#{120 * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L}"/>
```

What JVM options do I need to set? Should -xmx be set to 120g? Do I need to set MaxDirectMemorySize?

Answer (score 0):

You can set as much memory to your heap as if GridGain was not even there. For example, if your application requires 5GB on-heap, then just set -Xmx5g.

Also, GridGain open source edition is now [Apache Ignite](https://ignite.incubator.apache.org/) project. You can see [off-heap documentation](http://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.0/docs/off-heap-memory) in Apache Ignite project for more info.

Off-heap configuration settings were also discussed in [Apache Ignite Community Forum](http://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.0/discuss/551d3011e52a0b23000c61ac).